# A regular expression that convert below string to the "where" clause in sql

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to have a regular expression that convert below string to the "where" clause in sql.

​For example:

```
/* Col1: ABC, Col2: 123, ColN: Bla bla... */
```

to:

```
WHERE Col1 = 'ABC' AND Col2 = '123' AND ColN = 'Bla Bla...'
```

If this is something that feasible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this regex:

```
/\/\*|,|\s*([^:]+):\s+(.*?)(?=,|\s+\*\/)|\s+\*\//g
```

to match the individual components of the input: `/*`, `,`, `col: value` and `*/` and replace them with the appropriate values: `WHERE`, `AND`, `col = 'value'` and `''` using a [replacer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_function_as_the_replacement) function:

```js
data = '/* Col1: ABC, Col2: 123, ColN: Bla bla... */'

result = data.replace(/\/\*|,|\s*([^:]+):\s+(.*?)(?=,|\s+\*\/)|\s+\*\//g,
  (m, p1, p2) => {
    if (m == '/*')
      return 'WHERE '
    else if (m.endsWith('*/'))
      return ''
    else if (m == ',')
      return ' AND '
    else
      return `${p1} = '${p2}'`
  }
)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use a regex replacement here:

```js
var input = "/* Col1: ABC, Col2: 123, ColN: Bla bla... */";
var output = input.replace(/^\S+\s*|\s*\S+$/g, "")
                  .replace(/([^:\s]+):\s*([^,]+)/g, "$1 = '$2'")
                  .replace(/\s*,\s*/g, " AND ");
output = "WHERE " + output;
console.log(output);
```